# Grunt usemin task not updating nested relative paths correctly

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin, minimatch

I have a Yeoman project scaffolded with 'webapp-generator' which contains a static website with nested HTML files, resembling this structure:

```
-root/
  index.html
    -directory/
       file1.html
    -directory2/
       file2.html
    -js/
       (revved .js files)
    -css
       (revved .css files)
```

I'm using `usemin` and `filerev` tasks to update the filerevved file paths on the .html documents. It updates all file names correctly on js/css/images and it works correctly on the root `index.html`.
However, on the nested HTML files, it doesn't replace the reference to the correct nested path.

**For example.**

`js/scripts.js` gets renamed to `js/827385.scripts.js`

In **index.html**

`<scripts src="js/scripts.js"></scripts>`

resolves to: `<scripts src="js/827385.scripts.js"></scripts>`

But **in directory/file1.html** (or any other nested html file)

`<scripts src="../js/scripts.js"></scripts>`

gets also converted to: `<scripts src="js/827385.scripts.js"></scripts>`

Ignoring the **`../`** relative path

---

Is there any way to tweak the Grunt tasks to be aware of the relative depth of the file within the directories to keep the relative indicator `../` in the renamed path?.

Below is the code snippet for the relevant Grunt tasks.

PS: I have already followed some of the possible answers in this Stack Overflow question: [How should I configure grunt-usemin to work with relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964875/how-should-i-configure-grunt-usemin-to-work-with-relative-path) to no avail.

```js
     // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
        dist: {
          files: {
            src: [
              '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,**/}*.js',
              '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,**/}*.css',
              '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,**/}*.*',
              '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,**/}*.*',
              '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
            ]
          }
        }
      },

      // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
      // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
      // additional tasks can operate on them
      // <%= config.dist %>
      useminPrepare: {
        options: {
          dest: 'out',
          // root: '<%= config.app %>'
        },
        html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
          // root: '<%= config.app %>'
      },

      // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
      usemin: {
        options: {
          assetsDirs: [
            '<%= config.dist %>',
            '<%= config.dist %>/images',
            '<%= config.dist %>/styles'
          ]
        },
        html: ['<%= config.dist %>/**/*.html'],
        css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/**/*.css']
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I've found out that the problem was usemin configuration in the html files:

If you have in your **index.html** this usemin directive:

```
<!-- build:js styles/jquery.js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

In **directory/file1.html** you should try to use a full path in it:

```
<!-- build:js /scripts/jquery.js-->
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild-->
```

which will be converted to something like `<script src="/scripts/jquery.34ad31c3.js"></script>`.